# How to change the default double quote marks to single quote mark in Intellij(IDEA) once you press tab when you are writing HTML and CSS

Tags: css, intellij-idea

This is the default :

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Is there any setting to let it become

```
<div class='container'></div>
```

when you press tab?

Answer (score 30):

Editor > Code Style > HTML

I think you might be looking for Code Style Settings.

There is a drop down under "Generated Code" for String literal type: Single Quotes.

Change that.

You may also want to change it for JavaScript as well as Zhe points out, that is in the Punctuation tab.

Comment: I couldn't  find that in 2016.1 but it is right there at the bottom of the "Other" tab in 2016.2    Searching the preferences for "Generated" got me nothing of interest either.   Thank you for this.

Comment: For JavaScript it's in Punctuation tab :)

Comment: In my Mac WebStorm 2017.1.1, its in:
Preferences -> Editor -> Code style -> Typescript (orJavascript...) -> Punctuation tab -> use **single** (dropdown) quotes in new code.

Answer (score 5):

That is correct but the path is now (IJ 14) :

```
Editor | General | Smart Keys | XML/HTML
```

The option you are looking for is :

```
Add quotes for attribute value on typing '='
```

Comment: I'd love to know why the down vote.  This is still true as of IJ 16 btw.

Comment: I didn't down vote or try this answer, but this doesn't actually create single quotes instead of double quotes as asked in the question does it? @nycynik's answer worked for me.

Comment: RationalDev  that is correct and I'm pleased that IJ has fixed this.

Perhaps this should not have been an answer per-se, but at the time I could not comment.   This was an adjustment to the "at least you can turn it off" buy Mr. Dollery below.   Note that my answer was a full year before @nycynik's answer.   I don't think 14 or 15 supported nik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this isn't the answer you really want, but I don't think it can be altered.

You can switch it off completely though, under `Editor | Smart Keys | XML/HTML` there is is an option for adding quotes automatically that you can remove.

Answer (score 0):

**Update, years later - changing your mind.**

If, like me, you happily applied these tricks and got yourself set up to use single quotes in your HTML and then like me, realized you wanted to change back  you might find that you could fix it for HTML but not for XHTML.

For a year or more I have had this problem.   I do a fair bit of JSF/XHTML and this was killing me.  There is no code style in IntelliJ for XHTML and the XML code style (naturally) does not allow single quotes so this is not configurable there.

Changing the Setting back worked fine in HTML but had no effect in XHTML.  I was forced to exit IJ and edit the code style configuration manually. For me, in OS X it was in

`~/Library/Preferences/IntellijIdea2017.3/codestyles/<your code style>.xml`

There directly under the root element, I found the `HTML_QUOTE_STYLE` option :
`<code_scheme name="[REDACTED]">
   ...  some things snipped ...
  <option name="HTML_QUOTE_STYLE" value="Single" />`

If you change that "Single" to "Double" then you will be back to double quotes in your JSF.

It's possible however that I am the only idiot that had this problem.